# Renaming several git branches

Tags: git, bash

I am switching over to GitHub from a different git provider. I pulled all branches to my local with

```
for remote in `git branch -r`; do git branch --track $remote; done
```

but instead of getting branch named `name` I got them named `origin/name` so now I need to rename them to be just `name`.

Any ideas how to batch rename them? Or maybe just pull them with the right name would help too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for remote in `git branch -r`; do git branch --track $remote; done
```

Remote-tracking branches are conventionally referred to with their remote name as the first element, so `git branch -r` is showing you e.g. `origin/master`, `origin/release` and so forth. But your own branches aren't conventionally referred to with a prefix.

The full spelling of the remote-tracking branch `origin/master` is `refs/remotes/origin/master`, and what the branch command (and any other command that takes branch and tag names that don't start `ref/`) is doing is inferring what you're after by how you use it.

So for `git branch --track origin/master` you're using it as a local branch name.  What you probably want is

```
for remote in `git branch -r`; do git branch --track ${remote#*/} $remote; done
```

The `#*/` in `${remote#*/}` is part of the shell's parameter expansion features, find the "parameter expansion" in any shell docs, google 'man sh' and find that section.  It strips the shortest leading string matching the pattern `*/` from the expansion, so it'll strip `origin/` here.

Answer (score -1):

If you have 2 repositories,

The local is called `local`

And the remote is called `origin`

In the master branch of local, you can delete all the branches that start with "origin":

```
$ git branch -D origin/name_of_branch
$ git branch -D origin name_of_other_branch
```

etc.

Then,

```
$ git fetch origin
```

will allow local to work with the latest version of origin.  For each branch you want to pull down from origin:

```
$ git checkout -b name_of_branch
$ git rebase origin/name_of_branch
```

This will create branch "name_of_branch" in local and pull the changes from origin into that branch.

You also want to make sure that there are no conflicting changes in "origin".  If there are, post the issue and we can discuss it in a separate question.

Comment: this would work if i hadnt used the word "several" on the question. Good luck doing this to almost 400 branches